# Origin of Jessie

Tags: etymology

What's the origin of the name **[Jessie](https://web.archive.org/web/20160219205603/http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/jessie)** referring to an effeminate, weak, or cowardly boy or man?

Since English is a gender neutral language, it strikes me as curious to see the female name **Jessie** rather than the explicitly marked **Jessica**, for example,  applying to a male.

How is this?

Comment: In the US, we use "Mary".

Comment: Jesse James, Jesse Jackson, Jesse Helms, etc. It's a broad spectrum. In the South, naming your son 'Jesse James [surname]' was a thing at one time, really.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to (www.dictionarycentral.com):

> [Jessie :](http://www.dictionarycentral.com/definition/jessie.html) noun a weak or effeminate man.
>
> - A Scottish and northern English term of ridicule which **has become widespread since the mid-1970s, partly due to the influence of comics such as the Scot, Billy Connolly.** It is synonymous with nellie and big girl’s blouse.
> - There are two proposed derivations for the word; the first is simply a borrowing of the female name as a term of endearment, the second is a Biblical reference to ‘a rod out of the stem of Jesse’, giving rise to jokes on the subject of masturbation, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of sayings come from falconry. A Jess goes around the birds leg, then a cord attaches to the glove, so the bird does not fly away. A weak man that is a boy tethered to his mother's apron strings, is a big jessy!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's an interesting theory but it's no more plausible than the idea that it comes from a particular weak man called Jesse/Jessie, or a woman called Jessie, or some other explanation. That's why we need evidence.